# Database Design with thinking sphinx : week schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, thinking-sphinx

I need to implement a Week availability/schedule like this one on my App. Each User has his own week availabities :

[image: Week schedule]

I need to query my database and be able to find users who are available on specificics slots.
I tought I could implement 7x7 = 49 booleans attributes directly on my model , but I feel that it is not a very clean solution!

Other problem I'm facing : I wish to use Thinking_sphinx gem to index and query this content (and others attributes too) with facets navigation. 
There was a limit of facets numbers previsoulsy I don't know if it is still true.

Do you think it's better to use 49 boolean attributes or 1 single string attribute containing for exemple "Mo1 Mo2 Mo3 ..... Th1 Th6 Th7 Fr1 .....Su7" ?

Or any other solution ?

Comment: someone suggested me to use this gem https://github.com/pboling/flag_shih_tzu   
but taking care of performances issues :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099483/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-flags-flag-shih-tzu-can-handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that string attributes (as opposed to fields) can't be used in filters, and you'd want single string values for facets (not everything together in a single string), so I don't think your single string attribute suggestion will work out.

An alternative is search on the items *in* the schedule, get the user ids from that set, and then search across users *not* in that collection of user ids. It does mean two queries instead of one, but it's a little more obvious and a little less complex.